# Проблема с выводом данных json в recyclerView

Tags: java, android, json, recyclerview, jsoup

Пишу приложение, которое должно получать данные о курсе доллара с сайта с помощью jsoup  и выводить эти данные в recyclerView, но возникает следующая ситуация:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В добавок к этому я не знаю, как правильно передать данные json в recyclerView

Код:
Основная активность:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    RecyclerView recyclerView2;
    RecyclerView recyclerView3;
    RecyclerView recyclerView4;
    RecyclerView recyclerView5;
    RecyclerView recyclerView6;
    RecyclerView recyclerView7;
    RecyclerView recyclerView8;
    RecyclerView recyclerView9;
    RecyclerView recyclerView10;
    RecyclerView recyclerView11;

    private Document doc;
    private Thread secThread; // второстепенный поток
    private Runnable runnable;
    private ListView listView;
    private List<ListItemClass> arrayList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        init();
    }

    private void init()
    {
        runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
               // getWeb();
                refresh();
            }
        };
        secThread = new Thread(runnable);
        secThread.start();
    }

    // метод, в котором происходит заполнение recyclerView данными с сайта
    public void refresh(){
        try {
            recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
            recyclerView2 = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view2);
            recyclerView3 = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view3);
            recyclerView4 = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view4);
            recyclerView5 = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view5);
            recyclerView6 = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view6);
            recyclerView7 = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view7);
            recyclerView8 = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view8);
            recyclerView9 = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view9);
            recyclerView10 = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view10);
            recyclerView11 = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view11);

            // горизонтальное размещение элементов recyclerView
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, HORIZONTAL, false));
            recyclerView2.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, HORIZONTAL, false));
            recyclerView3.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, HORIZONTAL, false));
            recyclerView4.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, HORIZONTAL, false));
            recyclerView5.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, HORIZONTAL, false));
            recyclerView6.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, HORIZONTAL, false));
            recyclerView7.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, HORIZONTAL, false));
            recyclerView8.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, HORIZONTAL, false));
            recyclerView9.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, HORIZONTAL, false));
            recyclerView10.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, HORIZONTAL, false));
            recyclerView11.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, HORIZONTAL, false));

            ArrayList<newElements> list = new ArrayList<newElements>();
            ArrayList<newElements> list2 = new ArrayList<newElements>();
            ArrayList<newElements> list3 = new ArrayList<newElements>();
            ArrayList<newElements> list4 = new ArrayList<newElements>();
            ArrayList<newElements> list5 = new ArrayList<newElements>();
            ArrayList<newElements> list6 = new ArrayList<newElements>();
            ArrayList<newElements> list7 = new ArrayList<newElements>();
            ArrayList<newElements> list8 = new ArrayList<newElements>();
            ArrayList<newElements> list9 = new ArrayList<newElements>();
            ArrayList<newElements> list10 = new ArrayList<newElements>();
            ArrayList<newElements> list11 = new ArrayList<newElements>();

                doc = Jsoup.connect("https://yandex.ru/news/quotes/1.html").get();
                Elements tables = doc.getElementsByTag("tbody");
                Element our_table = tables.get(0);
                Elements elements_from_table = our_table.children();
                Element dollar = elements_from_table.get(0);
                Elements dollar_elements = dollar.children();
                Log.d("MyLog","Tbody size : " + our_table.children().get(0).text());
                for(int i = 0;i < our_table.childrenSize();i++ )
                {
                    ListItemClass items = new ListItemClass();
                    items.setData_1(our_table.children().get(i).child(0).text());
                    items.setData_2(our_table.children().get(i).child(1).text());
                    items.setData_3(our_table.children().get(i).child(2).text());
                    arrayList.add(items);

                    if (i == 0) list.add((newElements) arrayList); // приведение типов реализованно криво, но как сделать по другому, я не знаю
                    else  if (i == 1) list2.add((newElements) arrayList);
                    else  if (i == 2) list3.add((newElements) arrayList);
                    else  if (i == 3) list4.add((newElements) arrayList);
                    else  if (i == 4) list5.add((newElements) arrayList);
                    else  if (i == 5) list6.add((newElements) arrayList);
                    else  if (i == 6) list7.add((newElements) arrayList);
                    else  if (i == 7) list8.add((newElements) arrayList);
                    else  if (i == 8) list9.add((newElements) arrayList);
                    else  if (i == 9) list10.add((newElements) arrayList);
                    else  if (i == 10) list11.add((newElements) arrayList);
                }

            MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(list);
            MyAdapter adapter2 = new MyAdapter(list);
            MyAdapter adapter3 = new MyAdapter(list);
            MyAdapter adapter4 = new MyAdapter(list);
            MyAdapter adapter5 = new MyAdapter(list);
            MyAdapter adapter6 = new MyAdapter(list);
            MyAdapter adapter7 = new MyAdapter(list);
            MyAdapter adapter8 = new MyAdapter(list);
            MyAdapter adapter9 = new MyAdapter(list);
            MyAdapter adapter10 = new MyAdapter(list);
            MyAdapter adapter11 = new MyAdapter(list);

            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            recyclerView2.setAdapter(adapter2);
            recyclerView3.setAdapter(adapter3);
            recyclerView4.setAdapter(adapter4);
            recyclerView5.setAdapter(adapter5);
            recyclerView6.setAdapter(adapter6);
            recyclerView7.setAdapter(adapter7);
            recyclerView8.setAdapter(adapter8);
            recyclerView9.setAdapter(adapter9);
            recyclerView10.setAdapter(adapter10);
            recyclerView11.setAdapter(adapter11);

        } catch (Exception ex){

        }
    }
}
```

адаптер:

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.DataViewHolder>
{

    ArrayList<newElements> text;

    public MyAdapter (ArrayList<newElements> text){
        this.text = text;
    }

    public class DataViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView mTextView;

        public DataViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item);
        }
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public DataViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        return new DataViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull DataViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.mTextView.setText(text.get(position).getNum()); // поменять
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return text.size();
    }
}
```

класс ListItemClass:

```
 public class ListItemClass {
    String data_1;
    String data_2;
    String data_3;
    String data_4;

    public String getData_1() {
        return data_1;
    }

    public void setData_1(String data_1) {
        this.data_1 = data_1;
    }

    public String getData_2() {
        return data_2;
    }

    public void setData_2(String data_2) {
        this.data_2 = data_2;
    }

    public String getData_3() {
        return data_3;
    }

    public void setData_3(String data_3) {
        this.data_3 = data_3;
    }

    public String getData_4() {
        return data_4;
    }

    public void setData_4(String data_4) {
        this.data_4 = data_4;
    }
}
```

класс newElements:

```
public class newElements {
    private int num;

    public newElements(int num){
        this.num = num;
    }

    public int getNum(){
        return this.num;
    }
}
```

Comment: а зачем вам куча списков? или это такая задумка?

Comment: @Andrew, списки горизонтальные, для того, чтобы вводить в них курс доллара за каждый день (1 ряд - один день, в каждом ряду присутствуют дата, курс, изменение) данные с этого сайта https://yandex.ru/news/quotes/1.html

Comment: а почему нельзя все в одном списке отображать? я может конечно задаю глупые вопросы, но это мне пока не очень понятно) и второй вопрос - вы проверяли наличие данный в массивах которые передаете в адаптер, и проверяли ли вы хотя-бы начало прогрузки адаптера в onBindViewHolder?

Comment: @Andrew, в одном списке может и можно, но я не знаю как (так как в результате должно получится что-то вроде таблицы)
В массиве данных, скорее всего, нет, так как приведение у меня выполнено крайне криво (но я не знаю, как сделать по другому)

Answer (score 1):

Основная ваша ошибка в том, что вы вынесли в дополнительный поток всю инициализацию UI элементов. В методе onCreate() вместо init() вызовите сразу refresh().
Всё что связано с отрисовкой UI должно происходить в основном потоке. Все запросы в сеть, к БД, тяжёлые вычисления - в фоновых потоках.

Почитайте пожалуйста статьи про RecyclerView, не стоит плодить столько списков, когда можно обойтись одним, написав для него правильную модель.

Comment: с RecyclerView разобрался, но остальное пока что не получается